# unexpected T_STRING in buddypress member header

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

In buddypress you can add member profile fields to the member header, so beside their user avatar. In the buddypress member-header.php the section is commented out like so:

```
<?php
    /***
     * If you'd like to show specific profile fields here use:
     * bp_member_profile_data( 'field=About Me' ); -- Pass the name of the field
     */
     do_action( 'bp_profile_header_meta' );

     ?>
```

This is what I changed it to to add the profile field data "location":

```
<?php

     bp_member_profile_data( 'field=location’ );

     do_action( 'bp_profile_header_meta' );

     ?>
```

This code that I used gives me a T_STRING error in return. I have no PHP experience so I think it's an easy fix, given that the wordpress developers practically spell out how to use this feature.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighter shows your error. You have a funky quote:

```
   bp_member_profile_data( 'field=location’ ); <--HERE
```

Change it to:

```
    bp_member_profile_data( 'field=location' );
```

Comment: thanks for the response. How did you change that though?